# GAE How to indicate that a queue will run for hours?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_deadlines) indicate that a task :

> Tasks targeted at an automatic scaled module must finish execution
>   within 10 minutes. If you have tasks that require more time or
>   computing resources, they can be sent to manual or basic scaling
>   modules, where they can run up to 24 hours.

The link surrounding *[manual or basic scaling modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#set_module)* talks about a target, but doesn't say more about how to have a task that runs for a day.

You guessed my question :) How do I tell GAE that this specific task will be run for a day, not a minute ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure a module to use basic or manual scaling, deploy your task handling code to an instance for that module.

You can read more about configuring modules/versions/instances on the [App Engine Modules page for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/)

Comment: On a side, note, I'll flag the page you linked to for better clarification - if you've always used the default module on automatic scaling, the page you linked assumes someone has knowledge on module configuration then it should.

Comment: I would add that there is no set limit on how long a task can run if you use basic or manual scaling, but instances do restart sometimes. So it's better to split your task into smaller sub-task, or implement a shutdown hook.